# How to get values of current method without using reflection in java

Tags: java, logging, methods, reflection, reflections

I would like to create new **annotation** for logging method name and method's parameter value.

I'm using the below code to retrieve the method parameter information without using 'java reflection'(because its too costly).

```
    public void method1(String param1) {

    Method method = new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();

    System.out.printf(method.getName() + " : ");

    Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
    for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
        System.out.printf(parameter.toString());
    }
}
```

its output is :

> method1 : java.lang.String arg0

Here I'm getting parameter type and its name.
**I want to retrieve parameter value**

I had tried @Loggable annotation of https://aspects.jcabi.com/ and that is not working.

@Loggable references: (https://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-loggable.html) (https://aspects.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.22.6/com/jcabi/aspects/Loggable.html)

Comment: It's not possible via reflection. You're accessing the *definition* of the method. The definition of the method says nothing about any specific invocation.

Comment: That’s a weird question. All your code is doing, most notably `getClass().getEnclosingMethod()` and `method.getParameters()` **is** Reflection. If that’s not Reflection, what are you calling Reflection then? If you want a solution truly without Reflection, `System.out.println("method1: param1="+param1);` does the job.

Comment: Pretty sure the way you're trying to do it is outright impossible.  You'd probably have to do it by messing with the bytecode.

Comment: Well, while not "impossible", it would involve the use of some hidden, unsupported APIs[.](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/LiveStackFrame.java#L34) And writing a Java Agent is easier and better supported. It would also probably yield better performance.

Comment: My bad, getEnclosingMethod() is internally using reflection.
Basically I want to write an annotation which will log the method name and its parameter value.

Comment: Annotations don’t do anything. Annotations are like parameters or configuration file entries. You need actual software, e.g. an annotation processor, that does the job.